# rostopic echo shows wrong format of message from arduino

Tags: arduino, rosserial, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I made a custom message:
odometry_message:
Header header
int32 encoder1
int32 encoder2

Then I compile in into arduino sketchbook (rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries .)
I run a python serial node on arduino, set up a publisher that publishes such messages.
However when I user rostopic echo to show the message, it shows only two fields of a message:
encoder1
encoder2.
Also they are completely wrong.
If I remove Header field form the message and recompile, everything is okay and the values are valid.
Why can't rostopic echo display message in full format and why does adding header spoil the encoder values (issues w/serialization)?

Much thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201374/rostopic-echo-shows-wrong-format-of-message-from-arduino/) by [vd77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20364/vd77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2015-01-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-01-20**:
This sounds like your messages were not synchronized properly. The messages for the arduino must be the same as the ROS messages. A first check would be rosmsg show your/msg and see if that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, after 4 hours of pain I managed to get the result:
I deleted the whole build folder in catkin workspace, made clean and rebuilt project from the ground.
The wrong message format was cached somewhere deep.

---

Originally posted by [vd77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20364/vd77/) with karma: 38 on 2015-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0